# Socket.io installation failed | Windows 7 64bit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have installed NodeJs and the module 'express'. Now I want to istall socket.io, but it doesn't work. I've tried differend NodeJS versions, but all installations failed.

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/T8ZZRTML

Here is a screenshot: http://www10.pic-upload.de/31.01.13/ld98apo58e.jpg

Comment: Perhaps you want to give us a "preview" of your error. It might be unlikely that some really reads the external log.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://www10.pic-upload.de/31.01.13/ld98apo58e.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a native addon build error.  Do you have a [proper build environment](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) set up?

> - Python (v2.7.3 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
> - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 (Express version works well)
> - For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the Windows 7 64-bit SDK
> - If the install fails, try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributable that you have installed first.
> - If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may also need the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1